# Database not updating in Java

Tags: java, database, sql-update

The code doesn't want to update and says that there is an empty string when getting the currency name from the combobox(getCurType). Although it posts in the `println` statement post otherwise and shows it gets the correct thing from the `combobox`.

```
public void CurUpdate(){

     //*String str=currencyFrom.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //*String getRatesFrom= str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
    String str1=currencyTo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String getRatesTo= str1.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
    String getCurType=str1.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
    //*double ipa=Double.parseDouble(getRatesFrom);
    double opa=Double.parseDouble(getRatesTo);
    double ui=Double.parseDouble(inputAmount.getText());
    amountFrom=ui*opa;
    outputAmount.setText(""+amountFrom);
   double c=Double.valueOf(outputAmount.getText());
   //*String cc=String.valueOf(outputAmount.getText());
   System.out.println(""+c);
   System.out.println(getCurType);

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/currency","root","password");
        String sql="UPDATE logs SET res=res-? WHERE name=?";
        PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setDouble(1,c);
        pst.setString(2,getCurType);
        int i=pst.executeUpdate();

       if(i>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Table updated");

        }else{
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Can't update");
        }
     }catch(Exception e){}

}
```

Comment: I would start with logging of the exception thrown by the code.

If you don't understand the reason, post the exception here.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
 at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
 at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:416)
 at frames.Main.btnConvertActionPerformed(Main.java:507)
 at frames.Main.access$300(Main.java:28)
 at frames.Main$4.actionPerformed(Main.java:188)

Comment: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String at  " says that you are suppose to pass a string containing number value but it's empty, hence cannot be parsed as number. Try to debug it.

Comment: The problem was the db connection i fixed it.